# How to write Holder's inequality for random vectors?

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, random-variables, normed-spaces

For $1 < p,q < \infty$ satisfying the constraint $1/p + 1/q =1$ and for $X, Y$ random variables such that $\mathbb E [\vert X \vert ^p ], \mathbb{E} [\vert X \vert ^q   ] < \infty $ we have the Holder's inequality as,
$$\vert \mathbb{E} [ XY  ] \vert \leq \mathbb{E} [\vert XY \vert   ] \leq \Vert X \Vert_p \Vert Y \Vert_q  $$

- Can I somehow write the above for random vectors?
- For example with random variables $\{ u_i \}_{i=1}^{i=n}, \{ w_i \}_{i=1}^{i=n}$ is it always true that, $\mathbb{E} [\sum_i u_i^3 w_i  ] \leq ( \mathbb{E} [ (\Vert u \Vert_4 )^4 ]  )^{3/4} (\mathbb{E} [ (\Vert w \Vert_4 )^4 ] )^{1/4}$

---

Where any term of the type $\Vert Z \Vert_m$ means the $L_m$ norm (or the $m-$expectation norm ) of the random variable $Z$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write Holder's inequality for random vectors (for $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued functions more generally).

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{\Omega} |X^i(\omega)Y^i(\omega)|\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}\right]\leq \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{\Omega} |X^i(\omega)Y^i(\omega)|^p\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}\right]^{1/p}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{\Omega} |X^i(\omega)Y^i(\omega)|^q\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}\right]^{1/q}$$

Where $X^i$ and $Y^i$ denote the $i$th component of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.